# Check radio get value to array

Tags: php, javascript, radio

i have input radio as:

```
<input type="radio" name="payvalue" value="126500000"><br>
<input type="radio" name="payvalue" value="252000000"><br>
<input type="radio" name="payvalue" value="503000000" checked><br>
```

and a href get value to payment as

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.demo.com/button_payment.php?receiver=email@gmail.com&price=GET_VALUE_OF_RADIO">Pay Now</a>
```

How to change input radio get value of check to `price=GET_VALUE_OF_RADIO`

Any idea for hepls me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, let's put all the "payvalue" radio options into an array. This will allow us to then display them all using a `foreach` loop to reduce redundancy and the chance to make a mistake:

```php
$payValueOptions = [126500000, 252000000, 503000000];
```

Now, let's render the fields in a `foreach` loop:

```php
$selectedPayValue = $_GET['price'];

foreach ($payValueOptions as $option):
    $isChecked = ($selectedPayValue == $option);
    ?>

    <input type="radio" name="payvalue" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" <?php $isChecked ? 'checked' : '' ?>><br>

    <?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: i have list radio checked don't change it's. how to checked get value to `a href &price=VALUE_OF_CHECKED` after?